# CORS filter class in JAX-RS (Wildfly with RestEasy) not invoked?

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, keycloak, resteasy

#### Setup

- Wildfly 26
- Keycloak 16
- React frontend with `keycloak-js` adapter

#### Observed Behavior

When opening the frontend application, the user gets redirected to the Keycloak login screen. The login is succesful and the token issued by Keycloak gets stored in the browser's local storage. When the application calls the secured API, the token is present in the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.

Prior to any GET/POST request, the browser seems to send a preflight OPTIONS request which fails with a "CORS Failed" message in the browser console:

`Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`

**Request Headers**

```
OPTIONS /api/config HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Origin: http://localhost:3000
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-GPC: 1
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Expires: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: OAuth_Token_Request_State=381cd57a-82f3-44f0-b1af-c0e9764e86ab; path=/; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=admin-api&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8090%2Fapi%2Fconfig&state=381cd57a-82f3-44f0-b1af-c0e9764e86ab&scope=openid
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 15:55:10 GMT
```

While the error message makes sense and matches the response headers, I don't know the root cause.

In the JAX-RS server application I have the following `Feature` class but the code doesn't seem to get executed.

```java
@Provider
public class CorsFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.setAllowedHeaders("origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        corsFilter.setAllowedMethods("GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        corsFilter.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsFilter.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        corsFilter.setExposedHeaders("X-Total-Count");
        context.register(corsFilter);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Update 1

I replaced the `Feature` with the below `ContainerResponseFilter` and registered it in the `Application`:

```java
@Provider
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Total-Count");
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApiContext extends Application {

    private final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public ApiContext() {
        singletons.add(new CorsFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

At least the debugger hits a breakpoint when adding the `CorsFilter` but it still does not get invoked.

Comment: Are you sure the Feature is being registered?

Comment: My understanding was that classes annotated with `@Provider` get registered automatically?

Comment: Try a `DynamicFeature` since it is invoked post matching.

Comment: Using a `DynamicFeature` does not solve the issue. I think there is some underlying "basic" reason I don't see...

Comment: Did you try to register the filter inside `getClasses()` rather than in `getSingletons()`? I would frankly not understand why it could work better, but it may be worth trying

Comment: Forget it ! The doc clearly says: "You must allocate this and register it as a singleton provider from your Application class."

Comment: Huuum. Shoudn't your filter be registered as a **request** filter (> "*Resteasy has a `ContainerRequestFilter` that can be used to handle CORS preflight and actual requests*") ?

Comment: Looks like you are hitting the Oauth server.  You're getting a redirect response from the server.